# Tensorflow giving error '/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime....' on AMD when i import tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

**When i import TensorFlow i get this error**

The commands run but this error is hell of annoying

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1fLe.png)

Comment: Did you install TF with Python 3.5 ?

Comment: Finally solve the issue by uninstalling  tensorflow version 1.4.1 and installing version 1.5 using  `pip install tensorflow==1.5`